# What coordinates are chosen by default in Texture nodes?

Tags: node-editor, texture-coordinates

I have created a **texture coordinate** node and then deleted it. This action shows a small difference after rendering and I'm interested in describing this difference in words.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using an image texture, blender picks the "UV" Texture Coordinate by default. Procedural textures (ex: Noise Texture) use "Generated" by default. Generated represents the bounding box of your mesh, with coordinates 0,0,0 at the "bottom" corner.

Comment: To understand more about the differences in texture mapping watch this video: [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=265)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Christopher Bennett says in the comments, when you have no texture coordinate attached, it is picking a default for you, that default uses **UV** coordinates for mapping.

When you use **Generated** coordinates something interesting is happening.  It's attempting to map the image on the Z axis to your object, and since that axis doesn't exist for your two dimensional image, it's repeating the pixels at the edge of the texture along the Z axis of the object.